# How to resize table of database in swing frame?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am trying to resize the widths of the columns in a JTable.
I would need to resize them when the program is running to see the full column header names.
I want to resize table of database showing in swing frame.

I have tried

```
table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS)
```

But I didn't get the desired output because when I use this I have a horizontal scrollbar to scroll to the columns that are off screen. But I want the size of the whole table to become approximately equal to the size of frame.

How can I make the columns as wide as they need to be to display all the text?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But I want the size of the whole table to become approximately equal to the size of frame.

```
JTable table = ...;
JFrame frame = ...;
JPanel contentPane = new JPanel( new BorderLayout() );
contentPane.add( new JScrollPane( table ), BorderLayout.CENTER );
frame.setContentPane( contentPane );
```

> How can I make the columns as wide as they need to be to display all the text?

Unfortunately, the maximum width of the `JTable` will be limited to the size of the `JFrame`, and there is no mechanism to push from your `JTable` the desired width to the `JFrame` when your `JTable` is contained in a `JScrollPane`.

What you could do is try to give your `JScrollPane` the correct width. I haven't tried this, but I suspect that giving your scrollpane the same width as the preferred width of your table (when autoresize is on) should solve this (+ perhaps some extra width for the vertical scrollbar). Note however that this will only work if you allow your `JFrame` in which the `JScrollPane` is contained to grow in width as well.